# Cannot find material option for Alpha blend mode (Opaque, Alpha hashed , alpha clipped etc)

Tags: materials, transparency

I'm setting up the nodes for a transparent object (eyelashes and hair), and according to the tutorial I'm following I'm supposed to get the options in my materials panel to choose the blend mode. But I cannot find these options anywhere.

My node setup is with Principled BDSF, a transparency shader and a mix shader.

Annoyingly, I've actually done this before in other models, but cannot now get a menu that shows the blend options. Where have they gone? Am in 2.80 & Cycles.[image]

Comment: This option is EEVEE only.